# OL3 and html2canvas error while printing wms layer from local geoserver and osm layer as background

Tags: openlayers-3

I have OSM as a base layer in my application and on top of that I have few map layers that come from my local geoserver.

Now I need to print those layers and I have a layer control tool from which I can enable and disable layers.

If I remove all the layers from my local geoserver I can print (if only OSM layer is there) using html2canvas. But if layers from my local geoserver are visible I can't print.

Here is my complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Export map example</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.7.0/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.7.0/ol.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <div id="no-download" class="alert alert-error" style="display: none">
      This example requires a browser that supports the
      <a href="http://caniuse.com/#feat=download">link download</a> attribute.
    </div>
    <a id="export-png" class="btn" download="map.png"><i class="icon-download"></i> Export PNG</a>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
<script>
var baseLayerGeryBoundary = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mydata/wms',
          params: {'LAYERS': 'mydata:Road'},
          serverType: 'geoserver'
        })),
        name: 'Road Boundary',
        isBaseLayer:false,
        crossOrigin:true,
        visible:true
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'data/geojson/countries.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
      })
    }),
    baseLayerGeryBoundary
  ],
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
      collapsible: false
    })
  }),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});

var exportPNGElement = document.getElementById('export-png');

if ('download' in exportPNGElement) {
  exportPNGElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    convert(document.getElementById('map'));
  }, false);
} else {
  var info = document.getElementById('no-download');
  /**
   * display error message
   */
  info.style.display = '';
}



        function convert(target) {
            html2canvas(target, {
                "proxy": "html2canvasproxy.php",
                "logging": true, //Enable log (use Web Console for get Errors and Warnings)
                "onrendered": function(canvas) {
                    var img = new Image();
                        var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                        window.open(url, "_blank");
                    }
            });
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong here? I am using html2canvasproxy.php in my application. But still I can't print the layers.

This is the Message that I get:

```
html2canvas: Preload starts: finding background-images html2canvas.min.js:7:2811
html2canvas: Preload: Finding images html2canvas.min.js:7:2811
html2canvas: Preload: Done. html2canvas.min.js:7:2811
html2canvas: start: images: 1 / 1 (failed: 0) html2canvas.min.js:7:2811
Finished loading images: # 1 (failed: 0) html2canvas.min.js:7:2811
html2canvas: Renderer: Canvas renderer done - returning canvas obj html2canvas.min.js:7:2811
```

I get the image with openlayers zoom icons but no image, just gery image, but I have OSM as background and some layers on top of it.

AJ

Comment: seems like no one has the answer to this question :(

Comment: You should include the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a cross origin issue. You can solve it through properly configuring CORS headers from the server and the `crossOrigin` option, or by serving your tiles from the same host (natively or by proxy).

Note that the `crossOrigin` option should be a String, not a Boolean.

Comment: As you see in my code I am using a Proxy. But still I am having a problem. Just in case how do I configure CORS headers from the server and the crossOrigin option? I am using Geoserver for windows (installer version).

Comment: Your proxy is used by html2canvas when adding image elements from the DOM. It is not used by ol3 which loads the tiles and adds them to the map canvas, and thereby tainting it. You must make sure that the map canvas, as produced by ol3, is not tainted.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I don't know how should I do it. Can you suggest how should I do? Maybe a code sample would be helpful.

Comment: You should change your crossOrigin option to a string, such as "Anonymous". Then check the response headers of the loaded tiles, look for `Acces-Control-Allow-Origin`. If not there, enabling them is a question about server configuration. A good start might be http://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html

Comment: I will look at it today and update my situation. I hope I can fix this by today. I have geoserver 2.7.1 installer for windows. I will first uninstall and install the Apache version and then configure it. Thanks for the advice

Comment: managed to fix problem

steps

    uninstall geoserver
    Install geoserver.war
    Changed the web.xml  as mentioned by Alvin Lindstam 

    specified crossOrigin:"Anonymous" in my map layer

I am using "jspdf" instead of html2canvas. This gives me a nice PDF file and not Image.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You should mark the answer as accepted. Note that this was not related to html2canvas or jspdf, but to openlayers and the mapservers crossOrigin configurations.